# Facebook debugger reports "Curl error: 56 (RECV_ERROR)" when scraping content from my site

Tags: facebook, error, open-graph-protocol

Starting from today (16th May 2020), all of today's news from my website www.indozone.id cannot scrape anything (ex. https://www.indozone.id/health/gms7nka/diet-aktor-bollywood-hrithik-roshan-berpuasa-selama-23-jam).

I did not change any of the server configuration, nor change any firewall settings on my server? But `Curl error: 56 (RECV_ERROR)` keeps popping up when i'm using fb debugger.

And yes, it works fine yesterday.

Comment: "cannot scrape anything" - you mean, "cannot be scraped" presumably?

Comment: @MrWhite Yes, cannot be scraped, even the echo is empty: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.indozone.id%2Fnews%2Fmnso7y0%2Funik-kafe-di-jerman-ini-beri-pelanggan-topi-jaga-jarak-demi-hindari-covid-19